# WPF Possible to disable all click events in Window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, button, click

Would it be possible to disable all click events (mainly buttons) in a Window for 10 seconds, then re enable them?. I realize I could write code to manually disable all click events by calling them out: button1.IsEnabled=False (so on). However I have a lot of click events and I just wanted to see if I could disable them an easier way? If not its fine.

Example:

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

'Disable all click events in Window.
' timer to count to 10 then. 
' Enable all click events in Window.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by setting `IsHitTestVisible = False` on the Window.

If you want them to appear disabled, I believe you can just set `.IsEnabled = False`

Comment: That would work. Thanks. Would like them to look like their disable. However I shouldn't be picky. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminJones I think you can do that.. revised answer.